# How can I get numeric values without quotes in JSON after converting from XML

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, xml, asp.net-web-api

I have an XML from a stored procedure in SQL Server, this XML is converted into JSON and then returned from a Web API method.

This is how I'm converting XML to JSON

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(reportXmlString);
string jString = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jString);
return jObject;
```

I want to get numeric values in JSON as numbers... without quotes

What I have now

```
{
"Report": {
    "ReportItem": [
        {
            "Name": "MyObjectName",
            "Revenue": "99999.45"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

What I want to have

```
{
"Report": {
    "ReportItem": [
        {
            "Name": "MyObjectName",
            "Revenue": 99999.45
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I don't have any classes for this XML, I don't map it anywhere, I'm just receiving XML from stored procedure, converting it to JSON and returning it to user.

Here is XML which I'm parsing to JSON

```
<Report xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
<ReportItem>
    <Name>MyObjectName</Name>
    <Revenue>99999.45</Revenue>
</ReportItem>
</Report>
```

Is there any way to do this without creating a classes with types for each field?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it knows what datatype is inside so it treats everything as a string since that is most data safe. I looked at the settings options for Parse() but no luck. There is always an option to override Parse() or implement your kind of said parse with changed code that tests if something could be parsed as number then saves it as such :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit messy but you could write your own JsonConverter (this won't fix booleans as written if they're also coming out as strings):

```
class NumberConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out var d))
        {
                writer.WriteValue(d);
        }

        else
        {
                writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
        }
    }

    public override bool CanRead => false;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
string jString = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jString);

var fixedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject, new NumberConverter());
var fixedObject = JObject.Parse(fixedString);

return fixedObject;
```